# Python - Adding image to mp3 files in folder

Tags: python, for-loop, moviepy, pathlib

I have a folder with 10 ".mp3" songs, I want to add an image to those songs and render all files in mp4 format,
but I am getting an error : AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from pathlib import Path

music_folder = Path(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Audio')
Image = ImageClip(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Image\image.jpg')

for i in music_folder.glob("*.mp3"):
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(i)

    clip = Image.set_duration(audio_clip.duration)
    clip = clip.set_audio(audio_clip)

    clip.write_videofile('Final.mp4', fps=4)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(i)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_AudioReader(filename, fps=fps, nbytes=nbytes,
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 51, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 244, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AudioFileClip` class apparently can't accept a `pathlib.Path` argument; you'll need to convert it to a string.

```
AudioFileClip(str(i))
```

or convert the code to process strings instead of `Path` objects. (Basically, `import glob` and do `for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Audio', "*.mp3"))`

When `pathlib` was new, this was a quite common problem, so you can probably find duplicates of earlier questions about the same symptom. These days, you'd expect most libraries which accept files to also accept `Path` objects as arguments.

Comment: FYI: They have added support for Pathlib with this [pull request](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/1137) but I believe the OP uses older version of `moviepy`